# Cisco ASA active SwitchPort

Tags: firewall, cisco, cisco-asa

Does anyone know how to see which switch ports are cabled from CLI or ASDM?

I am configuring a 5505 and the inside has 6 interfaces associated, only one of which is actually actively linked.

I can't see to find this information, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Run the command:

`show interface`

This will output info about all the interfaces. The first line of each will say something like:

`Interface Ethernet0/2 "", is administratively down, line protocol is down`

If it is linked, it generally shows:

`Interface Ethernet0/1 "inside", is up, line protocol is up`

Comment: I can't up vote because that was my first question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the status of all the interfaces. Here is how you do.

## To view the interfaces connected

> show interfaces status | include connected

Gi3/2                        connected    28         a-full a-1000 10/100/1000-TX

Gi3/3                        connected    28         a-full a-1000 10/100/1000-TX

## To view the interface not connected

> show interfaces status | include notconnect

Te1/8                        notconnect   1            full    10G 10GBase-SR

Gi2/1                        notconnect   1            auto   auto 10/100/1000-TX

Gi2/2                        notconnect   27           auto   auto 10/100/1000-TX

Gi2/5                        notconnect   1            auto   auto 10/100/1000-TX

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

`show interface ip brief` shows some IP information, but also outputs interface status similar to a Catalyst switch:

```
Home# sh int ip b
Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
Ethernet0/0                unassigned      YES unset  up                    up
Ethernet0/1                unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
Ethernet0/2                unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
Ethernet0/3                unassigned      YES unset  up                    up
Ethernet0/4                unassigned      YES unset  up                    up
Ethernet0/5                unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
Ethernet0/6                unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
Ethernet0/7                unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
Internal-Data0/0           unassigned      YES unset  up                    up
Internal-Data0/1           unassigned      YES unset  up                    up
Vlan1                      x.x.x.x         YES DHCP   up                    up
Vlan2                      192.168.1.1     YES CONFIG up                    up
Virtual0                   127.0.0.1       YES unset  up                    up
```

And then to see vlans assigned use the `show switch vlan` command:

```
Home# sh switch vlan
VLAN Name                             Status    Ports
---- -------------------------------- --------- -----------------------------
1    internet                         up        Et0/0
2    inside                           up        Et0/1, Et0/2, Et0/3, Et0/4
                                                Et0/5, Et0/6, Et0/7
```